# Catch exception and save to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception

I'm catching an exception and I want to write this to SQL Server, but my program doesn't write...

I haven't received any error, but in SQL Server I haven't found anything...

```
catch (Exception f)
{ 
    String error = f.ToString();
    SqlConnection konekt = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

    SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand("insert into ERROR_LOG (ULOHA, OPERACE, POPIS, MESSAGE, DATUM) values ('3', '3', 'Chyba v ExportNOHEL', @error, @datum)", konekt);
    konekt.Open();
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@error", error);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", DateTime.Now);

    prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();

    konekt.Close();
 }
```

Have you any idea where is the problem?

Comment: Have you debugged in to this to ensure the exception has been thrown?

Comment: The code looks OK from what I can see. Did you single-step through the code?

Comment: Yes, but i havent any exception...

Comment: Are you sure the log table is not being cleared somehow when you look at it?

Comment: Start to attach a debugger. If you do not have any exception, you will not go into the catch block.

Comment: (sorry for stating the obvious) - are you definitely logging to the database you think you are?

Comment: I try catching the exception of this code and i havent any error...but in the SQL database i havent nothing...

Comment: Can you please show us the connection string you're using?

Comment: connection string is ok, because i use him more in program and in other its OK...

Comment: You do not have a `Try .. Catch` around you Sql calls in the current `Catch` block.  So how do you know that they are not returning an exception themselves?

Comment: I have, but i not write here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't getting any errors, and you are 100% sure that you are indeed writing to the correct database, then it may be that you have an ambient transaction, such as `TransactionScope` (which is rolling back your transaction)

A way to check this is to place a breakpoint on `konekt.Close();` and then switch to SQL Query Analyzer and do

```
select * from error_log (NOLOCK)
```

to see if the log is there. If it is, and then getting rolled back when you continue your code, you can suppress the ambient transaction as follows:

```
        using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        using (var konekt = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        using (var prikaz = new SqlCommand("insert into ERROR_LOG (ULOHA, OPERACE, POPIS, MESSAGE, DATUM) values ('3', '3', 'Chyba v ExportNOHEL', @error, @datum)", konekt))
        {
           konekt.Open();
           prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@error", "ASASAS");
           prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", DateTime.Now);
           prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
           konekt.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the datatype which you have it maybe that the data is getting truncated if `error` is too large. This might help:

[String or binary data would be truncated SQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825550/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-sql-error)

Answer (score 0):

altho there doesn't look to be anything wrong in what you are doing, hardcoding SQL statements into c# does make it difficult to debug, I would recommend creating a new Stored Procedure in the database for this, then you could monitor the action better, by creating a proper try catch in your stored procedure you could perhaps better discover what is going wrong.